# Pyaudio : how to compress audio stream

Tags: compression, pyaudio

I'm currently developping a VOIP tool in python working as a client-server as follows :

```
CHUNK = 1024
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16,
        channels = 1,
        rate = 44100,
        input = True,
        frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)

while 1:
    connection.sendVoice(stream.read(CHUNK))
```

How could I proceed to compress the sent data to spare connection, maybe increase speed, ...

Comment: sending chunks of 1024 is so small, you really need compress ??

Comment: Just saying 'hello' makes it send ~30000 characters (calculated summing len(stream.read(CHUNK)). Speaking continuously uses 0.7 Mbits/sec.

Comment: you can reduce the rate(like rate = 1024*10 or rate = 1024*15 etc ) to save size. btw i am facing same issue. can i contact you

Comment: @messi fan I saw your posts about it, we are looking for the exactly same thing. You can skype me at : thewarou. or by email?

Comment: @Waroulolz i am almost done. Hope i can give the answer by tomorrow

Comment: @messi fan I 'm curious to see what you've done

Comment: @messi fan Is the solution related to PyMedia ? I'm will trying some stuff with this library today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import time, sys,io
import pymedia.audio.sound as sound
import pymedia.audio.acodec as acodec
import pymedia.muxer as muxer


def voiceRecorder( secs, name ):
  f = open(name,'wb')
  secs = secs*5
  dm= muxer.Demuxer('mp3')
  snds= sound.getODevices()
  rt = 44100
  cparams= { 'id': acodec.getCodecID( 'mp3' ),
             'bitrate': 128000/4,
             'sample_rate': rt,
             'channels': 2 } 
  ac= acodec.Encoder( cparams )
  snd= sound.Input( rt, 2, sound.AFMT_S16_LE )
  snd.start()
  start_time = time.time()

  while snd.getPosition()<= secs:

   s= snd.getData()
   if s and len( s ):

     for fr in ac.encode( s ):
       f.write( fr)

    else:
      time.sleep(.25)



  snd.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  if len( sys.argv )!= 3:
    print 'Usage: voice_recorder <seconds> <file_name>'
  else:
    voiceRecorder( int( sys.argv[ 1 ] ), sys.argv[ 2 ]  )
```

Comment: you can also use lame dll (using ctype) to do this.if you can post ur email i can send you the code of that too. i have also the code for playing the  chunk

Comment: pls delete ur email now. i will send it

Comment: using ctype reduces portability to windows only (?) so i'm not very interested in, but reading the chunk would be great

Comment: ya. so i think above method is better option

Comment: Got it, sent one back ! There is an ugly noise through client server :(

Answer (score 1):

Wow for my calculations are you sending a little more that 2KB, to be exact 2.0480KB of audio at every loop to your socket connection:

```
(16 * 44.1 / 8)  * 1024/44100 = 2.0480
```

One simple way to send less data is reducing the `chunk` size if you change the chunk to `512` now are you sending just a bit more that 1KB.

Another way is try use `zlib` package in python to compress the `stream.read` data after send it through your socket, but for it do not forget to unzip in the other side.

Comment: Not wondering how much I send per loop, but how much I send for the complete word/sentence/... So chunk doesn't matter. Recording "Hello" will send more chunks of 512 than chunks of 2048 but both will send the same total of bits.

Comment: thx for zlib. It is doing the work with a ~20-30% reduction rate.