# Compress pyaudio stream with zlib

Tags: compression, zlib, pyaudio

I am trying to send audio from a microphone input between a server and client using pyaudio, I only need voice quality sampled at a rate of 8000. Without compression it works fine and I am trying to add zlib compression to reduce the bandwidth.

In my server the stream_callback function is

```
def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    for s in read_list[1:]:
        s.send(zlib.compress(in_data))
    return (None, pyaudio.paContinue)
```

In my client I am trying to decompress like this

```
try:
    while True:
        data = s.recv(CHUNK)
        stream.write(zlib.decompress(data, zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

I have tried various parameters with zlib.MAX_WBITS but all return this error:

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Edit: I have also tried with no second parameter with zlib.decompress

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong please, TIA

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second parameter of `zlib.decompress` at all. What you have in the question would look for a gzip stream instead of a zlib stream.

For compressing audio, you should use an audio compressor. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25961754/1180620).

Comment: Thanks for replying, I had already tried without the second parameter but that gave the error so I added that to try and fix the header check issue. I had already seen the answer you posted but was looking for a simple zlib solution to try get about 20% compression.

Comment: Then `data` is not the same as `in_data`. Have you looked at them, byte-by-byte? Is `CHUNK` guaranteed to read all of one `in_data` that was sent into `data`, and nothing else?